# Haskell: Wont compile with custom datatype

Tags: haskell

I am a beginner at haskell. Trying to create a program which allows you to enter a string and then manipulate it with different commands.

I've declared a new type called TextEdit which I want to store:
 -Text left of cursor (l)
 -Text right of cursor (r)
 -Text 'selected' by cursor (c)
 -and a clipboard for copy/cut/pasting (s)

```
data TextEdit l r c s = TextEdit { left :: l, right :: r, cursor :: c, select :: s }
```

or

```
data TextEdit l r c s = TextEdit { left :: [Char], right :: [Char], cursor :: [Char], select :: [Char]}
```

The rest of my code looks like this so far:

```
main = do
    putStrLn "-----Text Editor-----" 
    putStrLn "Please enter your text"
    tInput <- getLine
    let tI = TextEdit tInput "|" "" ""
    putStrLn "\n\n" 
    putStrLn tInput


moveCursorLeft :: TextEdit -> TextEdit
moveCursorLeft (TextEdit(l, r, c, s)) = (TextEdit(l, r, c, s))
```

The user will be calling 'moveCursorLeft tI' to move the cursor.

This is the error I am getting when I try to run it

```
TextEditor.hs:20:31: error:
* Expecting four more arguments to `TextEdit'
  Expected a type, but `TextEdit' has kind `* -> * -> * -> * -> *'
* In the type signature: moveCursorLeft :: TextEdit -> TextEdit
   |
20 | moveCursorLeft :: TextEdit -> TextEdit
   |                               ^^^^^^^^
```

Thanks for any help guys :) Really appreciate it

Comment: `Textedit` expects four type arguments in order to become a grown-up type you can reason about, i.e. `moveCursorLeft :: TextEdit String String String String -> TextEdit String String String String`

Comment: Grisha, I've added that to my code and it's giving me a different error now.

    TextEditor.hs:21:17: error:
    * The constructor `TextEdit' should have 4 arguments, but has been given 1
    * In the pattern: TextEdit (l, r, c, s)
      In an equation for `moveCursorLeft':
          moveCursorLeft (TextEdit (l, r, c, s)) = (TextEdit (l, r, c, s))
   |
21 | moveCursorLeft (TextEdit(l, r, c, s)) = (TextEdit(l, r, c, s))
   |                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: The `l r c s` after your TextEdit are _type_ arguments. If you want all of those to be `[Char]`, just leave them off. Also, you're constructing your TextEdit incorrectly - constructors are just functions, `TextEdit (l,r,c,s)` should be `TextEdit l r c s`

Answer (score 3):

```
data TextEdit l r c s = TextEdit { left   :: l, right  :: r
                                 , cursor :: c, select :: s }
```

So `TextEdit` is a type constructor that takes 4 type arguments, for example `TextEdit String String String String` would be a valid type.  You also have a data constructor of the same name, `TextEdit "a" "b" "c" "d"` would be a valid value of type `TextEdit String String String String`.

```
data TextEdit l r c s = TextEdit { left   :: [Char], right  :: [Char]
                                 , cursor :: [Char], select :: [Char]}
```

This is somewhat different and probably not what you want.  Here `TextEdit` is still a type constructor but the arguments do not appear on the right hand side - they are phantom.  Instead how about you use:

```
data TextEdit = TextEdit { left   :: [Char], right  :: [Char]
                         , cursor :: [Char], select :: [Char]}
```

Moving forward we will use this definition.  Now `TextEdit` is NOT a *type constructor* but it is merely a *type*.

```
moveCursorLeft :: TextEdit -> TextEdit
moveCursorLeft (TextEdit(l, r, c, s)) = (TextEdit(l, r, c, s))
```

Ah no.  You have used `TextEdit` correctly in the `main` routine but seem to have forgotten what you have learned.  `TextEdit (l,r,c,s)` says the text edit function takes one argument that is a 4-tuple of values.  However, looking at the data declaration we know `TextEdit` takes 4 arguments and they are all `[Char]` not tuples.  So use `TextEdit l r c s`.  Same goes for the function definition, yielding:

```
moveCursorLeft :: TextEdit -> TextEdit
moveCursorLeft (TextEdit l r c s) = TextEdit l r c s
```

To restate:  `(a,b,c,d)` is one value - a tuple.  `F (a,b,c,d)` is some constructor `F` applied to that one value.  `F a b c d` is the constructor `F` applied to four values.  Function application uses spaces and not parenthesis with commas - drop the C syntax.